# JQuery: how to use each in a result of find()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$.get(url, function(data){
    $("<div>" + data + "</div>").find('.list [class^=data]').each(function(){
        if($(this).is("[class^=dataitem]")){
            //code for dataitem
        }
        else{
            //code for not dataitem
        }
    });
});
```

With the get function I generate a strig variable with the code of the url page.
In this variable I find the tags, child of tag with class=list, whose class starts with "data" and for each of these control if the class starts with "dataItem" and if so apply the code for these tags.
Why doesn't it work?

Comment: I don't know! Do you get any errors in your console?! What does your request return exactly?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work? Please show us some sample input, what output you would expect (and let your script actually do something), and what you get instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
$.get(url, function(data){
     var YourFindElement = $("<div>" + data + "</div>").find('.list [class^=data]');
       $.each(YourFindElement , function (i, rowValue) {
          if($(this).hasClass("dataitem")){
              //code for dataitem
          }
          else{
            //code for not dataitem
          }
       });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The short answer. Because your selection doesn't return any objects. And there could be several reasons to this

you could change the code to

```
$.get(url, function(data){
    $("<div>" + data + "</div>").find('.list [class^="data"]').each(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("dataitem")){
            //code for dataitem
        }
        else{
            //code for not dataitem
        }
    });
});
```

which would remove the first of your problems (You need to wrap the attribute value in qoutes). However a much more likely cause is that you are looking at the attribute value so 
`class="hover dataitem"` will not match whereas `class="dataitem hover"` will. Therefor I'd suggest you change to

```
$.get(url, function(data){
    $("<div>" + data + "</div>").find('.list .data').each(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("dataitem")){
            //code for dataitem
        }
        else{
            //code for not dataitem
        }
    });
});
```

which will require you to add the `data` class to the elements in question and not just `dataitem`

Comment: You don't need to wrap attribute values in quotes, only if they contain invalid characters (like quotes, closing brackets, and similar).